# The Krein Milman theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am trying to understand the Krein Milman theorem from Rudin's Functional Analysis,  Second Edition  (page no 75). It has been shown that if $K $ is a compact convex subset of a topological vector space $X$,  then every compact extreme set $S$ has a non empty intersection with the set of all extreme points $E (K)$ of $K$. Herefrom how can I say that $K$ is a superset  of the closure of the convex hull of  $E  (K ) $?

Comment: Can you define "extreme set"?  In particular, I would think that an extreme set for $K$ is (by definition?) a subset of extreme points of $K$, but that would make your statement about "has a non empty intersection" somewhat obvious (perhaps the key aspect of that statement is just that extreme points exist?)

Comment: Of course, it seems you are asking about the "easy" direction, so I think that can be done without knowing the definition of the term "extreme set" used in your middle sentence: $$E(K) \subseteq K \implies Conv(E(K)) \subseteq Conv(K) = K \implies Cl(Conv(E(K)) \subseteq Cl(K) = K$$ where $Conv(K)=K$ holds because $K$ is convex; $Cl(K)=K$ holds if you can assume that the closure of a compact set is the same set back.

Comment: I have also got this. But just a little confusion about why $Cl(K)=K$? Is a convex compact set closed always? @ Michael

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}^n$, a set is compact if and only if closed and bounded. For more general spaces related-but-not-exactly-the-same results hold. Can you define "extreme set" and "closed set"?

Comment: So, you cannot define "extreme set" and "closed set" ?

Comment: Closed set means a set which contains all its limit points and a subset S of a tvs is called an extreme set if for any $X, y\in X $ and for  $t\ in  ( 0,1) $, $tx+(1-t )y\ in S  $ implies  $  X, y\in S$ @ Michael

Comment: I hope these are correct.  @ Michael

Comment: I got the answer.  Since every topological vector space is Hausedorff therefore every compact set in it is closed.  @ Michael